# can't connect any view controller to any class

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, viewcontroller

Hye there , i was trying to connect my view controller to a class and i just can't .

after i was selecting the view controller (from the black line under the screen) and open up

the identity inspector looking fot the right class at the drop down list - my class was not

there , so i copied the name of my class and i paste it into it and pressing "Enter" key i get

an error sound but i can't figure it out why?

1. I was trying to open new view controller  and not work
2. Trying to connect it to new class - and no .
3. Reopen Xcode after closing the Process .
4. Restart my MAC also .

cam anyone know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the answer !

when i changed inherit it was sold.

instead this -      **MYClass  : UITableViewController**

to this -             ***MYClass :  UIViewController***